# Is Microphone sensitivity and sound measure for loudspeaker adjustable in android?

Tags: android

Is Microphone sensitivity and sound measure for loudspeaker adjustable in android? If it can be , how can i do that (with which classes and methods)?
And how can i stimulate a phone call and send message when a little sound comes to phone?

Answer (score 0):

For API 16 you can use [AutomaticGainControl](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/audiofx/AutomaticGainControl.html), the AudioEffect and the AudioRecord to adjust gain, sampling and other pre-processing audio recording features.